# 4V AD590 interfaced to 3.3V MCU

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, stm32f4

I am using an AD590 temperature sensor that is interfaced to an STM32f427 MCU. 
It is a 2 pin sensor that must be connected to an ADC pin of the STM32f. But, the ADC590 needs a min of 4V to work and the STM32 is working on a 3.3V rail.

So, the first thing that comes up in my mind is using a voltage divider to step down from 4V to say 2.1V(which is my Vadc ref).

Is using a voltage divider advisable in such cases ? Also, should I then use resistors of high precision (say 0.1%) ?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "voltage divider"? You need at least 4V to power the sensor, judging by the data sheet... Could you post a circuit about how you would want to connect it?

Comment: The AD590 is a temperature to current transducer, so it would be useful to know how you are converting from current to voltage. Can you post your schematic?

Comment: What is the value of R40?

Comment: Just added the schemtic. Now, the ADCPIN net goes to the adc. But, since is 5V, I cannot feed it directly to the adc, as the STM32 is a 3.3V device. So, probably I will need to add a voltage divider. Also, I will do the math by connecting the voltage via the ADCPIN and the GND pin thereby finding out the current using ohms law.

Comment: @SteveG. Is that relevant ?

Comment: @Board-Man yes. The value of R40 determines the maximum voltage going to the ADC pin (at 150 deg C). Get the value of R40 correct and you don't need to divide the signal down.

Comment: @SteveG. Thank you for the support. Another thing. If at all I need to use a voltage divider, is it an issue loading such a network onto an ADC pin ? Will measurements be erronous ?

Comment: In this particular case, where you are in effect measuring small currents, you would have to be very careful not to introduce errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just reduce the resistor to keep the voltage within range over the expected temperature range.

Keep in mind that if the temperature sensor wires get shorted the MCU will likely be destroyed. It's also not very good to run long wires directly to the MCU pins.

I suggest adding a resistor of 1-5K in series with the ADC input and a capacitor from the ADC input to ground of 100nF X7R.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8pmLf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Do pay attention to Equation 1 in the microcontroller [datasheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00071990.pdf) to ensure that you are not exceeding the **maximum sample rate** for the input impedance (which will be your load resistor plus the series resistor I mentioned plus Radc - the 6K ADC sampling switch resistance). Since the AD590 sensors respond with glacial swiftness by ADC standards, you can simply keep the sample rate within reason and you won't lose any information.

[image]

Also note that you will not be able to get a full 3.3V out of the AD590 with only a 5V supply. Check the datasheet. You may be limited to 1V to get guaranteed accuracy.

Comment: Personally I would add a zener parallel to C1. But then, I also don't know what Microchip says about the resistor to 5V thing on analogue inputs. Not many mfgs like that as an option.

Comment: @Asmyldof It's only to protect the chip in case of catastrophic shorting. It cannot be expected the circuit to operate properly in such circumstances, even unshorted inputs would likely suffer. By the way, you cannot realistically use a zener in this application- the voltage-current curve of a 3.3V zener would not protect the input and would **totally destroy the accuracy**.  It's preferable to use a switching diode (**not** Schottky- too much leakage) to a clamped voltage  (shunt regulator) of perhaps 3.1V using eg. TL431 + R's- but this is better than the OPs original circuit and is simple.

Comment: Spot on about the leakage of course. My bad. I intended to point out that in ADC mode many pins become more sensitive to the "attenuate with an R" trick and forgot to consider that this is a uA scale, even though your picture states it. A second option would be to add an extra resistor tot he sensor path that would get it to voltage dividing 5V into 3V at short. Less safe than hard protection in the long-wire argument, but still, an option.

Comment: @Asmyldof  The voltage divider is not a bad idea in general. Unfortunately the drop-out voltage of the AD590 is really high so I don't think it will be good in this instance.

Comment: I guess I give up trying to annoy you into additions then ;-). I do notice I forgot to upvote you the first time I came here (I promise I meant to).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany. If I understand right the adc in a MCU consists of a capacitor that is charged up(which constitutes the acquisition time of an adc). If I have a capacitor as you recommend, would it not throw m,y adc reading off balance ?

Comment: If the total resistance R2+Rload  is in line with eq1 then no, it will not be significantly affected. The cap actually helps.

Answer (score 4):

This sensor produces a current output. 
From [the data sheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD590.pdf): 
 "The device
acts as a high impedance, constant current regulator passing
1 μA/K."
Just choose your R40 to not go over the STM32's 3.3V limit and you won't need any voltage divider.

Comment: So, in other words the sensor can be assumed as a variable resistor(that regulates current flow depending on temp). This resistor in conjunction with the R40, will give me a reading of the temp mapped current. And since it is high impedance sensor, loading it with a resistor to the GND will pull the voltage. Intelligent selection of R40 will help me maintain it less than 3.3V.


So, I will need another ADC pin that taps into the base of the R40 (or rather at the ground).

Comment: A variable resistor could be misleading, you should consider it as an ideal current source, with the current output being set by the temperature. If the ground is in common with the STM32, which should be, you don't need another pin.